# Android - Dalvik virtual machine processes

Tags: android, linux, dalvik

I would like to investigate the behavior of processes on a dalvik virtual machine. I wonder if I can run the machine itself on a linux environment? How to manage such a machine? Can new processes be started? I do not have knowledge in this area and I would be grateful for any information.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does Android even use Dalvik any more?

Comment: Related documentation: [Android Runtime (ART) and Dalvik](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik)